# My keyframes disappeared and the common solutions I found doesn't (seem) to work (2d animation)

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil

I tried scrolling up the timeline, but it doesn't show anything (I only see summary, and the rest is blank); I tried an answer that said click view -> frame all, I made sure I had selected the object that had the keyframes in object mode and still nothing.

I think before it disappeared I was readjusting the camera in the view menu on the right, so I'm not really sure if that messed with anything?

I apologize that this is quite a redundant question, but I'm not aware of any other solutions that could help my problem-

Edit : this also happens for my other blender files ;w;

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's because you changed the UI space for your timeline. Try changing the section highlighted in the image below (Dope Sheet) to **Grease Pencil** and see if that makes your layers visible again:

[image: Grease]

Comment: Whoops, aight, I forgot to make sure I had the object selected and clicked on the summary arrow. Oh my gosh I am so sorry for adding to your notifs 